# How to run app linked with glibc.so on android

Tags: gcc, glibc

compiler is gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-i686_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz, app run on armv7 android4.4 device

My C code is test.c,

```
#include"stdio.h"
int main(void)
{
        printf("starting...\n");
        return 0;
}
```

If i compile it use command:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o test_s test.c -g -Wl,-rpath=.:./lib -Wl,-rpath=.:./lib -Wl,-q -Wl,-dynamic-linker=ld-2.21.so -static
```

it can work well:

```
root@test:/data/mine # chmod 555 test_s
root@test:/data/mine # ./test_s
starting
```

But, if i compile it use command:

```
 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o test_d test.c -g -Wl,-rpath=.:./lib -Wl,-rpath=.:./lib -Wl,-q -Wl,-dynamic-linker=ld-2.21.so
```

it gives me the error:

```
root@test:/data/mine # chmod 555 test_d
root@test:/data/mine # ls -l test_d
-rwxrwxrwx root     root        12316 2018-04-19 13:37 test_d
root@test:/data/mine # ./test_d
/system/bin/sh: ./test_d: Permission denied
```

I have copied the required dynamic libs to the path /data/mine/lib

How should I deal with this problem?

**update**

before run command mount -o remount,exec /data
the command mount return:

```
/dev/block/platform/comip-mmc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
```

after run **mount -o remount,exec /data**
the **mount** return:

```
/dev/block/platform/comip-mmc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
```

I run **strace  ./test_d** again,it give me same result EACCES.
I think "EACCES The filesystem is mounted noexec" is not the root reason, because the test_s is in the same directory, and run correctly

I try to compile with command: **arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o test_d_ndl test.c -g  -Wl,-rpath=.:./lib**

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-readelf -d test_d_ndl
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000f (RPATH)                      Library rpath: [.:./lib]
```

I copy the libc.so.6 to path /data/mine and run commond

```
root@test:/data/mine # ls -l
-rw-rw-rw- root     root       774660 2018-04-20 13:32 ld-2.21.so
drwxrwxr-x root     root              2018-04-17 14:43 lib
-rw-rw-rw- root     root      9180280 2018-04-20 16:50 libc.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx root     root        13808 2018-04-18 16:56 test
-rwxrwxrwx root     root        12316 2018-04-20 13:31 test_d
-r-xr-xr-x root     root        10520 2018-04-20 16:46 test_d_ndl
-rwxrwxrwx root     root         3348 2018-04-20 09:47 test_ld
-rwxrwxrwx root     root      3672356 2018-04-19 09:58 test_s

root@test:/data/mine # strace  ./test_d_ndl
execve("./test_d_ndl", ["./test_d_ndl"], [/* 25 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "strace: exec", 12strace: exec)            = 12
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "No such file or directory", 25No such file or directory) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

test_d_ndl give the error reason ENOENT, what can i do next?

**update**

use following command works well

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc test.c -o test_r_dl -Wl,-rpath=/data/mine/libc/lib -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/data/mine/libc/lib/ld-2.21.so

Comment: The compiler is gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-i686_arm-linux-gnueabihf

Comment: Regardless of yor permission problems, making an executable world writable will never do any good.

Comment: Yes, I've changed the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i compile it use command: ... `-Wl,-dynamic-linker=ld-2.21.so` ...

Using relative path for `--dynamic-linker` is *ill*-advised: your app will run IFF there is a `./ld-2.21.so` in your current working directory.

> I have copied the required dynamic libs to the path `/data/mine/lib`

Since you are not in `/data/mine/lib` when you are starting the binary, and assuming you didn't *also* copy `ld-2.21.so` into `/data/mine`, your dynamic linker will not be found.

However, *usually* this is reported with `ENOENT` rather than `EPERM`, so I am not sure that is your real problem. Running `strace ./test_d` may provide additional clues.

**Update:**

> `root@test:/data/mine # strace ./test_d
>   execve("./test_d", ["./test_d"], [/* 25 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied) ...`

The `execve` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) says:

```
EACCES The filesystem is mounted noexec.
```

which sounds like it may be the immediate cause of your error.

(Once you `mount -o remount,exec /data/mine`, it will likely start failing with `ENOENT` instead.)

Comment: <br>root@test:/data/mine # strace ./test_d<br>
execve("./test_d", ["./test_d"], [/* 25 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)<br>
write(2, "strace: exec", 12strace: exec)            = 12<br>
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2<br>
write(2, "Permission denied", 17Permission denied)       = 17<br>
write(2, "\n", 1<br>
)                       = 1<br>
exit_group(1)                           = ?

Comment: i am sorry, i try to add space, br, or new line to format the comment, but it do not take effact...

Comment: I can't format the comment, so I've updated the question,@Employed Russian

Comment: You are right! I've tried **arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  test.c -o test_r_dl -Wl,-rpath=/data/mine/libc/lib -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/data/mine/libc/lib/ld-2.21.so**,and it works. Thank you very much!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/851229#851229